# Javascript Attribute not updating after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bootstrap modal I use for a deletion confirmation. After I submit a entry delete it will not work again until I reload the page. I am using javascript to watch for button click. The id attribute is passed to another function and submitted via ajax. The data-id attribute it not updated and still has the old button data-id.

I am not sure how to make the id attribute reset without reloading the page. Any help is appreciated. Sorry new to coding.

Here is the Button Code:
`<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm_delete_modal" name="delete_btn" id="' + clockData.id + '" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete"></button>`

Here is the JS:

```
//Trigger Delete Confirmation Modal
$(document).on('click', '.btn_delete', function () {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
 $('#delete_confirm').attr('id', id); //set the data attribute on the modal button

});

// Trigger Ajax delete function
$('#delete_confirm').click(function(){
var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
            url: "/clock/delete",
            method: "POST",
            data: {id: id},
            success: function (data) {

                $('#confirm_delete_modal').modal('hide');
                search_data();

            }
        })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first run, the `id` attribute of the (previously) `#delete_confirm` button is actually changing, since you're resetting it via `$('#delete_confirm').attr('id', id);`. When the `.btn_delete` handler runs a second time, there is no `#delete_confirm` to change the `id` of, since it is now the `id` from the first delete button click.

The best solution with your implementation would be to use the `data-id` attribute, instead of the actual `id` for tracking which delete button was clicked.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn_delete', function () {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
 $('#delete_confirm').data('id', id); //set the data attribute on the modal button
});

// Trigger Ajax delete function
$('#delete_confirm').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).data('id');

  $.ajax({
    url: "/clock/delete",
    method: "POST",
    data: {id: id},
    success: function (data) {

      $('#confirm_delete_modal').modal('hide');
      search_data();

    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `data('id')` to get attribute `data-id`

`$(document).on('click', '.btn_delete', function () {
       var id = $(this).data('id'); // 
       $('#delete_confirm').attr('id', id);
 });`